# Can't get negative sign in calculator to disappear

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm working on an iOS 5 calculator that contains the following code:

```
- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{

//Enter digit, avoiding two-decimal-point case.
NSString *digit = sender.currentTitle;
NSRange range = [self.display.text rangeOfString:@"."];
if (range.location==NSNotFound || (![digit isEqualToString:@"."]))
    if (self.userIsEnteringNumber)
    {
        self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:digit];
    }
    else 
    {
        if (![sender.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"."])
        {
            self.display.text = digit;
        }
        else 
        {
            self.display.text = @"0.";
        }
        self.userIsEnteringNumber = YES;
    }
}
```

and

```
- (IBAction)changeSignPressed 
{

//Reverse sign from positive to negative or vice versa.
if (self.numberIsNegative) self.numberIsNegative = NO;
if (!(self.numberIsNegative)) self.numberIsNegative = YES;

//Correct display to reflect change in sign.
if (self.numberIsNegative)
{
    if (![[self.display.text substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"-"])
    {
        self.display.text = [@"-" stringByAppendingString:self.display.text];
    }
}
if (!self.numberIsNegative)
{ 
     /*This isn't working--why not?
    if ([[self.display.text substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"-"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Okay."); //This doesn't log, so obv. the problem is in the previous line.
        self.display.text = [self.display.text substringFromIndex:1];
    }
     */
}
}
```

I can't get the commented-out code in changeSignPressed to work no matter how I fiddle with it.  Any ideas about how I can fix this?

Comment: To further debug the problem, try putting `NSLog(@"!numberIsNegative");` directly above the commented-out code and see if you hit that.

Comment: Random unrelated note: try `[self.display.text hasPrefix:@"-"]` rather than using substring. It's much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably this code:

```
//Reverse sign from positive to negative or vice versa.
if (self.numberIsNegative) self.numberIsNegative = NO;
if (!(self.numberIsNegative)) self.numberIsNegative = YES;
```

There is no `else` so if `self.numberIsNegative` is initially `YES` it will become `NO`; it will then be immediately seen as `NO` on the following line where it is changed back to `YES`.

In any case, that code is more complex than it needs to be; you can just say this to invert a flag:

```
self.numberIsNegative = ! self.numberIsNegative;
```